# Synchronization on class object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was reading a tutorial on concurreny when i read the following example:

> Here are the same two examples as static methods. These methods are synchronized on the class object of the class the methods belong to:

```
    public class MyClass {

    public static synchronized void log1(String msg1, String msg2){
       log.writeln(msg1);
       log.writeln(msg2);
    }


    public static void log2(String msg1, String msg2){
       synchronized(MyClass.class){
          log.writeln(msg1);
          log.writeln(msg2);  
       }
    }
  }
```

> Only one thread can execute inside any of these two methods at the same time.
>
> Had the second synchronized block been synchronized on a different
>   object than MyClass.class, then one thread could execute inside each
>   method at the same time.

I just want to make sure that I get this right.

So you can't call in a single thread the methods log1 and log2 at the same time? But if the synchronized wasn't on the class object you could?

It's more the translation that is bothering me I guess.

*An example with comments is appreciated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So you can't call in a single thread the methods log1 and log2 at the same time? But if the synchronized wasn't on the class object you could?

To be precise, you can't call the methods log1 and log2 in *different* threads at the same time.  Declaring a method `static synchronized` has the same effect as synchronizing on the class object.

Here's an example where the second method synchronizes on the `log` variable instead of the class.

```
public class MyClass {

  public static synchronized void log1(String msg1, String msg2){
    log.writeln(msg1);
    log.writeln(msg2);
  }

  public static void log2(String msg1, String msg2){
    synchronized(log){
      log.writeln(msg1);
      log.writeln(msg2);  
    }
  }

}
```

In this case, two separate threads could execute `log1` and `log2` simultaneously because they synchronize on different objects: `log1` on the `MyClass.class` object, and `log2` on the `log` object (wherever that is defined).

Here's the key thing to remember about synchronized methods and blocks:

1. The synchronized code has to synchronize using the *same object instance*
   across all threads.
2. Classes are objects too!  There's typically just one instance of a given Class's object, created when the class is first loaded.

Comment: Just one more question, if you would change the method log2 to use synchronized(this) could you then call both methods at the same time or is it still locked on the class?

Comment: Two things: 1) You can't reference `this` inside a static method.  2) `this` refers to an *instance* of MyClass, which is a different object than MyClass.class. So, ignoring point 1, you would be synchronizing on different object instances, so two threads would be able to run log1 and log2 simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

No. The two methods are both synchronized on MyClass.class. So if one thread calls any of the methods, another thread can't call any of those two methods at the same time.

If one method synchronizes on another object, then the two methods aren't mutually exclusive anymore, and one thread can call log2 while another thread calls log1.

Answer (score 1):

> So you can't call in a single thread the methods log1 and log2 at the same time?

You can't call any 2 methods at the same time from single thread. You can call the same method from one thread and another thread at the same time.

When this situation occurs (if method is synchronized) first thread who acquire the lock (in your case it is `MyClass.class`) will execute synchronized block and then release the lock. Only after it another thread can try to acquire the lock and continue execution.

You have 2 methods both synchronized on `MyClass.class`. It means that if the first thread acquire `MyClass.class` lock (it can dot it by calling `log1` or `log2`) then the second thread, if he wants to execute anything locked by MyClass.class (in your case any of the methods `log1` or `log2`), must wait until first thread releases this lock to execute.

> But if the synchronized wasn't on the class object you could?

This means that one of the methods is synchronized on `MyClass.class` and another is synchronized on something else (for non-static default is `this`).
They have different locks so they can be executed simultaneously from different threads.